# Problem in logging in to the system

Tags: 11.04, login

I am using Ubuntu 11.04 on my PC. I face a problem when I log in as some other user other than administrator. The error message is as follows:

> This is a problem with a configuration server.(/usr/lib/libgconf2-4/gconf-sanity-check-2 exited with status 256)

Any solutions?

Comment: try `sudo chmod 1777 /tmp` then reboot

Comment: i tried this,but found nothing changed. The other problem i am facing is I cannot delete the other users using USERS AND GROUPS even being an ADMINISTRATOR.

Comment: it is also giving me another message as "COULD NOT FIND /home/theja/desktop" and "/home/theja/.nautilus"

Answer (score 1):

Try executing this in terminal:

```
sudo chmod 1777 /tmp
```

I hope this may solve the issue.